# Recursive call uncaugth

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, recursion

I'm doing a project for school.

In the project there are courses, but the courses have previous courses.

A course looks like this:

```
"id": "math3",
        "previous": ["math2", "math1"],
        "name":"Gestión de Proyectos",
        "proffesor":"Viviana Rocco",  
        "credits":"4,5",
        "description":""
```

I have a list of courses, and inside the courses there are another previous courses. Further I have a HTML when all the courses are showed, so want to make a function that if we do a hover over the course box the previous courses boxes change their colour.

So i made this functions:

```
function paint(id) {
        for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    
            if (materias[i].id === id && (courses[i].previous.length > 0)) {
    
                for (j = 0; j < courses[i].previous.length; j++) {

                    if (courses[i].previous[j] !== null) {
                        document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,99,71,0.5)";
                        document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0.2rem rgba(220,20,60,0.5)";
                        paintPrevious(courses[i].previous[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    }

    function paintPrevious(courseId){
        for (i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
            if (courses[i].id === courseId) {
                if(courses[i].previous !== null && courses[i].previous.length > 0){
                    for(j = 0; j < courses[i].previous.length; j++){  // This line the exception
                        document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(214, 132, 56,0.5)";
                        document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0.2rem rgba(220,20,60,0.5)"
                        console.log("pinto")
                        paintPrevious(materias[i].hijo[j]); // recursive call
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

but when the function  paintPrevious recieve as parameter a course tath dont have a previous they trows a exeption

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'previous' of undefined
```

Comment: `course[i]` But such a variable is never defined, the variable name is `courses`

Comment: What does the entire `courses` structure look like?

Comment: Is an array of courses

Comment: In this line, `if (materias[i].id === id && (courses[i].previous.length > 0))`, you try to access the `length` property of `courses[i].previous`, without first checking that `courses[i].previous` exists.  Also, this line uses `'materias'`.  Should that be `'courses'`?  If you fix these, does it solve your problem?

Comment: These lline is ok, materias and courses are the same.
Translation problems hehe

Comment: The problem round about "undefined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems here.  First of all, there is the naming issue I mentioned in the comments.  Second is the fact that you're checking `courses[i].previous[j] !== null`, when that should not be necessary, but if it was, you probably need to check against `undefined` instead... and you can do both by checking `!= null` (one equals sign.)

But the big problem is that you're not declaring your loop variables.  `i` and `j` are not declared, and so are global.  When you change `i` inside `paintPrevious`, you are also changing it inside `paint`.  Changing `for (i = 0; ...)` to `for (let i = 0; ...)` and similarly for `j` fixes your problem.

```js
const courses = [
  {id: "math1", name: "Class 1"}, 
  {id: "math2", previous: ["math1"], name: "Class 2"}, 
  {id: "math3", previous: ["math2", "math1"], name: "Class 3"}
]

// build the HTML from the courses.
courses.forEach(course => document.getElementById('courses').innerHTML += 
  `<div id = '${course.id}'>${course.name}  (prerequisites: ${(course.previous || []).join(', ')})</div>`
)

// test the paint function
paint('math3')

function paint(id) {
  for (let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    if (courses[i].id === id && courses[i]. previous != null && (courses[i].previous.length > 0)) {
      for (let j = 0; j < courses[i].previous.length; j++) {
        if (courses[i].previous[j] !== null) {
          document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(255,99,71,0.5)";
          document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0.2rem rgba(220,20,60,0.5)";
          paintPrevious(courses[i].previous[j]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}


function paintPrevious(courseId){
  for (let i = 0; i < courses.length; i++) {
    if (courses[i].id === courseId) {
      if (courses[i].previous != null && courses[i].previous.length > 0){
        for(let j = 0; j < courses[i].previous.length; j++){  // This line the exception
          document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.backgroundColor = "rgba(214, 132, 56,0.5)";
          document.getElementById(courses[i].previous[j]).style.boxShadow = "0px 0px 0px 0.2rem rgba(220,20,60,0.5)"
          paintPrevious(courses[i].previous[j]); // recursive call
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id = "courses"></div>
```